# Piping tail -f into awk

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, logging, awk

I am trying to pipe tail -f into awk to monitor a logfile in realtime, but according to examples, there should be not problem but I can't get it to work.

here is the command I'm running

```
tail -f logfile.log | awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}'
```

But when I edit my file using nano add a line, it is not printed in real time, If I run the awk command directly, my new line appear in the result.

Comment: [How to “filter” a tail output throug awk and grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164964/6521116)

Answer (score 16):

You don't see it in real time because, for purposes of efficiency, pipes are buffered.  `tail -f` has to fill up the buffer, typically 4 kB, before the output is passed to `awk`.

A fix is to use the unbuffer command which is part of the expect package:

```
unbuffer tail -f logfile.log | awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}'
```

This tricks `tail` into thinking it is writing to an interactive terminal. As a result, it doesn't buffer.

For more, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Alternatively, if you have GNU coreutils 7.5 or better, you can disable output buffering with the stdbuf command:

```
stdbuf -o0 tail -f logfile.log | awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}'
```

Comment: Sadly the stdbuf solution does not seem to work either.

Comment: But you are right that if I add ~10 rows, the buffer is flushed. So while the code works, the unbuffered part doesn't

Comment: I just fixed a typo in the stdbuf command.  Other than that, there might be an additional issue with your editor not updating the file in a way that triggers `tail`.  Can you try just appending to the file without the editor. For example, run `date >>logfile.log` a couple times in one window and see if `awk`, running in another window, prints the updates.

Comment: Yes I did tried echo "My long string here" >> logfile.log
from a different putty window.

When I execute that line about 10 times the awk command will execute.

Comment: @gimpycpu Using `nano`, I got various results depending on how I edited the file before saving.  Using `echo "My long string here" >> logfile.log`, however, it works every time for me.

Comment: If you can add this, I will mark your answer.

It looks like that with debian and ubuntu, stdbuf does not work with awk, I find out that I could use mawk instead with that command, and it works

`tail -F logfile.log | mawk -Winteractive -F" " '{print $1, $2}'`

Answer (score 6):

[@John1024's alternative answer](https://superuser.com/a/742247/87805) is not quite correct, as the `stdbuf -o0` prefix is misplaced.  It belongs as the prefix to the `awk` command, not the `tail -f` command, so the correct command should be:

```
tail -f logfile.log | stdbuf -o0 awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}'
```

This is what worked for me, BUT only after I located an awk version that would cooperate.  So note that ***not all versions of awk allow this!***  I had to try nawk, gawk, mawk, etc until I found one that worked.  If you need that particular command string to function as written, keep trying various awk/gawk/mawk versions by being explicit with the path of the awk binary and even downloading others until you hit one that works.

Comment: I used the comment link to do that, but it prevented me due to not enough reputation.  What means should I have used?

Comment: Suggest the change to the post to which you had the suggestion (['improve this answer'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246755) option). Even anonymous users can do that.

Comment: There is no "Improve this ..." anything as an option for me.  Sorry, kenorb

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 20.10 where `awk` links to `mawk` version 1.3.4,

Add `-W interactive`.  E.g. `tail -f $file | awk -W interactive '{print}'`

(Thanks to the other folks whose answers here caused me to read the man page looking for `buffer`.)

Comment: Nice catch of the new feature

Comment: this works for me , thanks .

Comment: tried all the other solution here, this one is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You could un-buffer it by adding a while loop as given in the example below. I have tested this on a running log file and it worked for me.

```
tail -f input.log | while read a; do echo "$a" | awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}' >> output.log; done
```

Comment: You generally want to avoid piping into `while read` if you can . If you can't, putting the `awk` pipe after the `done` would somewhat improve performance.  But anyway, the proper fix is to disable buffering, not work around it.

Comment: This helped me view log messages on an embedded system that lacked `unbuffer` and `stdbuf`

Comment: This will create a new `awk` process per each line, instead of running it once.

Answer (score 1):

Neither stdbuf nor unbuffer seem to work for me (Ubuntu 18.04), but using a named pipe does. I created a shell script containing:

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}' < /tmp/pipe &
tail -f input.log > /tmp/pipe
```

Comment: The stock version of awk has not been good to me with stdbuf, like you've discovered.  Eventually I chanced on a version of awk/gawk/nawk/mawk that would work, but the REAL question in my mind is whether the stdbuf capability of awk is destined to become less prevalent or more amongst the collection of awks.  And by the way, I applaud your use of named piping.  One-liners are more useful, however, in many situations.  Do you think you can put all that into one line like cron for instance would need?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with this problem, it appears that buffering issues can affect both the read and write sides of each command. In my case, I had a command like the following:

```
$ parallel ... | ggrep ...
```

This worked fine, printing output as it was produced by `parallel`. When I tried to process further with `awk`, though:

```
$ parallel ... | ggrep ... | awk ...
```

I didn't see output until `parallel` was done. I naturally thought the issue was with `awk`, hence finding this post, so I tried this:

```
$ parallel ... | ggrep ... | stdbuf -o0 awk ...
```

But what actually fixed it was this:

```
$ parallel ... | stdbuf -o0 ggrep ... | awk ...
```

So it appears that `ggrep` can tell when it's printing vs. hooked up to another command, and buffers its output in the latter case. (Incidentally, `ggrep` actually has a `--line-buffered` flag which fixes my problem as well.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Not sure what all the fuss is about:

```bash
tail -f mylog.txt | awk -f ~/mylog.awk
```

Your thinking too hard. Check your fire.